# Effect of periodic acid on trans diols of 3, 4 and 5 membered rings

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, alcohols

Does periodic acid cleave the following diols?

- *trans*-cyclopropane-1,2-diol
- *trans*-cyclobutane-1,2-diol
- *trans*-cyclopentane-1,2-diol

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt that any of the **trans** diols is cleaved.

The reaction is assumed to proceed through a cyclic intermediate, which is unlikely to be formed in any of the cases.

Comment: Are you 100 % sure that *trans* diols aren't cleaved. According to the book by Kurti and Czako (http://www.amazon.com/Strategic-Applications-Reactions-Organic-Synthesis/dp/0124297854/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1392294686&sr=8-2&keywords=czako%2C+kurti) a similar reaction, the Criegee Oxidation, in which vicinal diols are cleaved by $\ce{PbOAc4}$, works with both *cis* and *trans* diols (although the reaction with *trans* diols is slower).

Comment: @Philipp Very interesting! But was it shown for 5-membered rings too? The successful cases for *trans* diols I know are pyranoses, whereas I've not seen it for furanoses. But I'm not too old to learn :)

Comment: I haven't dived in the referenced papers and couldn't find anything for the ring diols. But in the book by Smith and March (http://www.amazon.com/Marchs-Advanced-Organic-Chemistry-Mechanisms/dp/0471720917/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1392295682&sr=8-3&keywords=smith+march+organic) it is also claimed that *cis* **and** *trans* react, while the reaction with *cis* is faster (see pp. 1734-1735). There you can even find that (4ar,8ar)-decahydronaphthalene-4a,8a-diol (sorry, I don't know the trivial name) is cleaved by $\ce{PbOAc4}$ (though other glycols that cannot form cyclic esters are not cleaved).

Comment: Apperently, there is the possibility of a mechanism involving a cyclic transition state (without the cyclic intermediate), that allows for *trans* compounds to be cleaved (see p. 1735 or Criegee, R.; Höger, E.; Huber, G.; Kruck, P.; Marktscheffel, F.; Schellenberger, H.
*Liebigs Ann. Chem.* **1956**, *599*, 81.).

Comment: No problem, the IUPAC name is fine, even on a train ;-)

Comment: "IUPAC names on a train" sounds a bit like a horror movie to me :)